# Xamarin.iOS. VTDecompressionSession.Dispose locks main thread

Tags: xamarin.ios

I try to decode hevc video stream via VTDecompressionSession. When I call VTDecompressionSession.Dispose from main thread for releasing resources sometimes the method locks the thread.

What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO ! Calling the Dispose method when the application is finished using the VTDecompressionSession ensures that all external resources used by this managed object are released as soon as possible. Once developers have invoked the Dispose method, the object is no longer useful and developers should no longer make any calls to it.

Answer (score 0):

When releasing the VTDecompressionSession, it is important to make sure all the frames are done being processed. In the case of Xamarin, you should make sure the frames are finished by calling this before calling Dispose:

```
VTDecompressionSession.WaitForAsynchronousFrames()
```